# Call to the class created for SharedPreference is not happening

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Created separate class to execute sharedPreference while the API call takes place in activity I tried calling the SharedPreference class in the activity but the Call is not Happening?

```
public  void saveInt(Context context, String key, String value) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling _saveInt_ method?

Comment: In activity as call Happens in the activity as

Comment: `SaveData save;
@Override
                        public void response(String response)  {
                            try {
                                Log.d("String arg0 login", "yes " + response);
                            JSONObject respons = new JSONObject(response);
//                            progressDialog.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Token = respons.get("access_token").toString();
                                Log.d("access token", Token);
                                save.saveInt(context, "access token", Token);}``

Comment: your _save_ object is not initialized. Like `SaveData save = new SaveData()`

Comment: How to initialize it?

Comment: working fine thanks

Comment: don't turn your code into `try...catch` just to avoid a crash. Or you won't get any info about why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Please Check This,

This is my own created class

```
public class ShardPref {

    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;

    private static final String PREFERENCES = "bgvs_app";

    private static final String IS_USER_LOGIN = "is_user_login";
    private static final String BRANCH_ID = "branch_id";
    private static final String EMP_ID = "emp_id";
    private static final String USERNAME = "user_name";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "user_password";
    private static final String USER_TYPE = "user_type";


 public ShardPref(Context mContext) {

        mPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }



public void setUserData(String strBranchId, String strEmpId, String strUsername, String strPassword, String usertype) {
        mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
        mEditor.putString(BRANCH_ID, strBranchId);
        mEditor.putString(EMP_ID, strEmpId);
        mEditor.putString(USERNAME, strUsername);
        mEditor.putString(PASSWORD, strPassword);
        mEditor.putString(USER_TYPE, usertype);
        mEditor.apply();
    }

    public String getBranchId() {
        return mPreferences.getString(BRANCH_ID, "");
    }

    public String getEmpId() {
        return mPreferences.getString(EMP_ID, "");
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return mPreferences.getString(USERNAME, "");
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return mPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, "");
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return mPreferences.getString(USER_TYPE, "");
    }


}
```

After This just call

```
 private ShardPref mPref;

 mPref = new ShardPref(LoginActivity.this);
// Set Data
 mPref.setUserData(set data here);
// Get Data
mPref.getEmpId();
```